# Keeping track of fragments in an activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity with 3 fragments (A, B and C). Fragment A is added to the activity `onCreate` and it's also not added to the `backstack`.

Navigation flow for this activity can be:

A -> B -> C, or
A -> C

Pressing back or `navigateUp` on fragments B or C should return to the previous fragment.

The code to add fragments to the activity is:

```
private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.container_fragments, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());

    if (addToBackStack) {
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
    }

    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.commit();

    currentFragment = fragment;
}
```

And the code to get the current fragment is:

```
private Fragment getCurrentFragment(){
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0)
        return null;

    String tag = fm.getBackStackEntryAt(fm.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getName();

    return getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
}
```

I'm overriding `onBackPressed` and `onNavigateUp` as follows:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    currentFragment = getCurrentFragment();
    if (currentFragment == null) {
        currentFragment = fragmentA;
    }

    setHeader();
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigateUp() {
    if (currentFragment == fragmentA) {
        return super.onNavigateUp();
    }

    else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        currentFragment = getCurrentFragment();

        if (currentFragment == null) {
            currentFragment = fragmentA;
        }

        setHeader();
        return true;
    }
}
```

`setHeader` is a method to change the header text of the activity depending on the current fragment being displayed.

The above works if I navigate from A to C and backwards. However, for navigating from A to B to C and backwards is not working. When going back from C to B, the code thinks that it's already on A (header text for A is displayed), but fragment B is being shown.

Is the above not the correct way to handle the backstack? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just check in onBackPress that count is >0 than pop fragment, and write code of setHeader in onCreateView of fragment.

Answer (score 0):

This code is doing good, you may check once.
    public void pushFragments(String tag, Fragment fragment,boolean shouldAnimate, boolean shouldAdd) {

```
    if (shouldAdd)
        mStacks.get(tag).push(fragment);
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    if (shouldAnimate){
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            ft.setCustomAnimations(0, 0);
        }

    ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
    ft.commit();
//  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "+"+ mStacks.get(mCurrentNavigatorMenu).size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void popFragments() {
    /*
     * Select the second last fragment in current tab's stack.. which will
     * be shown after the fragment transaction given below
     */
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+ mStacks.get(mCurrentNavigatorMenu).size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Fragment fragment = mStacks.get(mCurrentNavigatorMenu).elementAt(mStacks.get(mCurrentNavigatorMenu).size() - 2);

    /* pop current fragment from stack.. */
    mStacks.get(mCurrentNavigatorMenu).pop();

    /*
     * We have the target fragment in hand.. Just show it.. Show a standard
     * navigation animation
     */
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);

    ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
    ft.commit();
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (((BaseFragment) mStacks.get(mCurrentNavigatorMenu).lastElement())
            .onBackPressed() == false) {
        /*
         * top fragment in current tab doesn't handles back press, we can do
         * our thing, which is
         * 
         * if current tab has only one fragment in stack, ie first fragment
         * is showing for this tab. finish the activity else pop to previous
         * fragment in stack for the same tab
         */
        if (mStacks.get(mCurrentNavigatorMenu).size() == 1) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);// or call finish..
        } else {
            popFragments(); 
        }
    } else {
        // do nothing.. fragment already handled back button press.
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nothing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code is working fine for navigation. I remove the `setHeader` method and moved it here:

```
    final FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    fm.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            Fragment fr = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.container_fragments);
            if(fr!=null){
                currentFragment = fr;
                setTitle();
            }
        }
    });
```

This way I know which fragment is currently being displayed and set the header
accordingly.